# Filter out Mirrors in array

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

```
let mirror_arr=[ [1,2],[3,2],[1,4],[8,1],[5,4],[2,1],[3,5],[1,8],[3,2],[2,3] ]

filtered_mirror=[ [1,2],[3,2],[1,4],[8,1],[5,4],[3,5] ];
```

This algorithm filter out all the mirror ones. For example, `[1,2]` is a mirror of `[2,1]`, so it will be filtered by removing the mirrors. Are there any short method to do this in Javascript? Thank you for reading :) My codepen solution is [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/xxpQwMW?editors=0012) and I am almost solved it. It is just that I have to remove the duplicate ones.

Comment: Loop through the first array. Check if the current element or its mirror is already in `filtered_mirror`. If not, push it.

Comment: A more efficient way would be to create a nested array. Check if `array[current[0]][current[1]]` or `array[current[1]][current[0]]` already exists. If not, add it.

Comment: This may be useful in case you want to generalize to subsrrays with more than two items: [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that you don't want duplicates either as you didn't have a second `[3,2]` in your expected output. From your codepen it looks like you're familiar with Set and JSON.stringify .

```js
let mirror_arr = [ [1,2],[3,2],[1,4],[8,1],[5,4],[2,1],[3,5],[1,8],[3,2],[2,3] ];

let filtered = [];
let found_set = new Set();

for(let i = 0; i < mirror_arr.length; i++) {
  let item = mirror_arr[i];
  let string_item = JSON.stringify(item);
  
  if(!found_set.has(string_item)) {
    filtered.push(item);
    found_set.add(string_item);
    found_set.add( JSON.stringify([...item].reverse()) );
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for guidance. Actually, I have already solved it haha. You can see my updated codepen above. different code but same output. I am removing the items one by one when mirror pair is detected